# Parallelizability of Lie monoids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, semigroups-and-monoids, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

A *Lie monoid* is a monoid, together with a structure of a smooth manifold (possibly with a boundary), such that the monoid multiplication is smooth.

If all left (or right) translations in a Lie monoid $M$ have full rank at the identity $e$, then the monoid is necessarily parallelizable, since any basis of $T_eM$ may then be extended to a left-invariant (or right-invariant) global frame for $TM$. In particular, this holds for any Lie group. Furthermore, any Lie monoid $M$ that admits an injective immersive homomorphism $\phi\colon M\rightarrow G$ into a Lie group $G$, is parallelizable. That is, any Lie submonoid of a Lie group is parallelizable.

However, left and right translations in a Lie monoid may not have full rank at identity, indicating that in general, a Lie monoid may not be parallelizable. The question hence reads: **Do non-parallelizable Lie monoids exist?**

A useful insight to this question stems from the theory of H-spaces. Since H-spaces are generalizations of topological monoids, and the only spheres that admit a H-space structure are parallelizable, spheres don't admit such a Lie monoid structure. Due to cohomology, projective spaces are also disqualified. Furthermore, there exist H-spaces which are not parallelizable (see e.g. *Browder, Spanier*: [**H-spaces and duality**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1962.12.411), Pac. J. Math. 12, 411-414 (1962). [ZBL0112.14502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0112.14502).), but the given example is quite involved.

Comment: I think any non-parallelizable sphere is an example of non-parallelizable semigroup, where monoid operation is just vector space addition compactified by infinity which becomes an absorbing element. You can freely adjoin a disjoint identity point to get a monoid. I'm not able to produce a connected (or even equidimensional) example, unfortunately.

Comment: The monoid operation (denote it $m\colon S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^n$) you are talking about is not even continuous: take any sequence of vectors $v_n\rightarrow \infty$, and then $(v_n,-v_n) \rightarrow (\infty, \infty)$, but $m(v_n,-v_n)=0$ whereas $m(\infty, \infty)=\infty$. So $m$ does not map limits to limits. Also, $0$ is the identity element, so you didn't have to adjoin it.

Comment: Take a unital associative finite-dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, and consider it as a Lie monoid under multiplication. Translation by zero does not have full rank.

Comment: Of course, but this is an example of a parallelizable manifold, a vector space. My question is whether we can find a *non-parallelizable* Lie monoid.

Comment: @ŽanGrad: Right, I misunderstood this.